# Saving arrays/parameters when using forms in Python CGI

Tags: python, parameters, save, cgi

I've been working on a small test that's going to be on a website, using Python and the cgi module, to test the Astronomy knowledge of the user. The test uses what questions have been given, and the answers to these questions, when deciding which new question to give. To achieve this I need to, for each user, keep a couple of arrays with information on which questions have been given. These arrays are updated throughout the session.

I'm using forms, and I'm able to save a value connected to which answer the user chooses. However, I haven't found a good way to keep my arrays each time the user chooses an answer (i.e. reloads the page). I've looked into cookies, but I can't find any good tutorials/examples, and I'm having trouble progressing, especially as I'm on a tight time schedule. Does anyone know how to save arrays (or other types of parameters) when the user inputs an answer to the form? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CGI is considered ancient and should be avoided when building python web apps.

Use a modern python web framework instead, probably [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (or [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) for a microframework).

For example, Django has built in support for server side [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/) which can hold your data.